# add new record to many to many relation in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I was trying to add new relation to many to many records,

for example i have these models:

models.py

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, unique=True, max_length=100)
    players = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='players')



class TeamInvite(models.Model):
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='invite_by', blank=True, null=True)
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='invite_to', blank=True, null=True)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='invite_to_team', blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.NullBooleanField(blank=True, null=True, default=None,)
```

and my serializer:

serializers.py

```
class TeamInviteCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    team = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Team.objects.all())
    from_user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all())
    class Meta:
      model = TeamInvite
      fields = ('id', 'from_user', 'to_user', 'team', 'status')
```

after that the user which in to_user will take an action to TeamInvite like accept or decline.

I need the serializer which will take the new user and add him to the existing team like the following serializer:

```
class TeamInviteAcceptDeclineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    method_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = TeamInvite
        fields = ('id', 'from_user', 'date_time', 'team', 'method_name', 'status')

    def get_method_name(self, *args, **kwargs):
        method_name = None  # kwargs['context']['request'].method_name
        return method_name

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.team = validated_data.get('team', instance.team)
        method_name = validated_data.get('method_name')
        instance.status = validated_data.get('status', instance.status)
        instance.to_user = validated_data.get('to_user', instance.to_user)

        if method_name == 'decline':
            instance.status = False
        else:
            instance.status = True
            team = Team.objects.get(pk=instance.team.pk)
            team.players.add(instance.to_user)
            # team.players.create(team_id=team, user_id=instance.to_user)
            team.save()
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

`update` function does not add the user to existing team and doesn't raise any error either. What am i missing here?

my request was:

```
{
    "from_user": 1,
    "to_user": 23
    "team": 64,
    "method_name": "accept",
    "status": null
}
```

thank you

Comment: could you please add the request with which you hit this API?

Comment: check updated post please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the missing point in my code..
it was in:

```
class TeamInviteAcceptDeclineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    method_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = TeamInvite
        fields = ('id', 'from_user', 'date_time', 'team', 'method_name', 'status')
```

`fields =` missed 'to_user' pram